# Concatenate xml parent and child attribute values using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, concatenation

I would like to concatenate the parent value of an attribute with the child value of a different attribute and also remove specific attributes from an xml file. My input xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<import_data>
    <product part_number="12345" category="Parts and Accessories" description="Small-Part">
        <product_attribute name="organizationCode" value="XYZ"/>
        <product_attribute name="Product Market" value="Rotors"/>
        <product_attribute name="inventoryItemId" value="6789">
    </product>
    <product part_number="ABCDE" category="Ball Bearings" description="Small-Part">
        <product_attribute name="organizationCode" value="XYZ"/>
        <product_attribute name="Product Market" value="Rings"/>
        <product_attribute name="inventoryItemId" value="FGHIJ">
    </product>
</import_data>
```

and the output should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<import_data>
    <product part_number="12345" category="Rotors.Parts and Accessories" description="Small-Part">
        <product_attribute name="Product Market" value="Rotors"/>
    </product>
    <product part_number="ABCDE" category="Rings.Ball Bearings" description="Small-Part">
        <product_attribute name="Product Market" value="Rings"/>
    </product>
</import_data>
```

My xsl looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml"  encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<!-- Identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="//so_product_attribute[@name='inventoryItemId']" />
<xsl:template match="//so_product_attribute[@name='organizationCode']" />

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have figured out how to drop the unwanted elements (inventoryItemId and organizationCode) but I can't figure out how to read the value of the child element (product_attribute name="Product Market" value="Rotors") and combine it with the value of the parent attribute's (product category="Parts and Accessories") attribute so that it combines into (product category="Rotors.Parts and Accessories"). I have experimented with using xsl:for-each and reading the value of the child into a variable but I am not able to concatenate and output the desired value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly tweaked your XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  >
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml"  encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product[normalize-space(product_attribute[@name = 'Product Market']/@value)]/@category">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(parent::product/product_attribute[@name = 'Product Market']/@value, '.', .)"/>  
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product_attribute[@name='inventoryItemId']" />
  <xsl:template match="product_attribute[@name='organizationCode']" />

  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- added matching template for `product/@category`, if `@value` of `product_attribute[@name = 'Product Market']` is a non empty string. [this avoids a dot in front of the category, if absent]
- create new attribute with same name and concat the `@value` with a `.` and the content of context-node (current attribute).
- changed `so_product_attribute` to correct name of input-element
- don't start with `//` in matching patterns.

Comment: Thank you very much. Was able to implement your changes and it worked perfectly. Additionally, your notes helped me to understand the reasoning behind your xsl.

Comment: Closing the question by marking a answer as accepted would help me and the community. Please accept if all your requirements are answered.